# How to process an activity recieved from a skill in bot framework v4?

Tags: c#, azure-bot-service, botframework

I'm developing a skill consumer bot using Microsoft Bot Framework v4 for C#, my skill is a dialog bot developed in Bot Framework Composer, my question is: Is it possible to process the activity received from a skill bot before show it to the user? The reason of this is because I want to send an ID Code (that identified the real message in a Database) as a response from the skill, and used this ID to obtain the real answer registered in a database that is connected to my skill consumer bot. And then show the real answer to the user. I saw in official Bot Framework doc the skill handler is used to receive the activities from the skills (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-consumer?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#skill-client-and-skill-handler).

Skill handler description in official doc:

[image: 1]

I checked the skill handler class and I saw the following methods:

```
protected override Task OnDeleteActivityAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string conversationId, string activityId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
protected override Task<ResourceResponse> OnReplyToActivityAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string conversationId, string activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
protected override Task<ResourceResponse> OnSendToConversationAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string conversationId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
protected override Task<ResourceResponse> OnUpdateActivityAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string conversationId, string activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Does any of this method can help to get what I'm looking for? If yes, how should I use this, or what can I do?

I hope you can help me.

PD: Sorry for my English. I'm from Peru :D

Comment: Is the skill consumer built in Composer, or just the skill?

Comment: @Kyle Delaney just the skill. Skill consumer is built in C#

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard. Have you tried implementing your own skill handler and overriding `OnSendToConversationAsync` and `OnReplyToActivityAsync`?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution using a middleware. I created a class GetSkillResponseMiddleware.cs to write all logic.

```
public class GetSkillResponseMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // Here I can add logic to process messages sent by user. 
        // Example: Register user's message data in a telemetry app.

        // Register outgoing handler.
        turnContext.OnSendActivities(OutgoingHandler);

        // Continue processing messages.
        await next(cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<ResourceResponse[]> OutgoingHandler(ITurnContext turnContext, List<Activity> activities, Func<Task<ResourceResponse[]>> next)
    {
        foreach (var activity in activities)
        {
            if (activity.Type == "message")
            {
               // For example I want to concat the phrase "Bot said: " to all messages sent by the bot. In my real case I edit the answer sent by the skill bot.
               activity.Text = $"Bot said: {activity.Text}";
            }
        }

        return await next();
    }
}
```

In the code above, the method OutgoingHandler process all activities sent by the bot, I use a condition to process only messages activities. In my arquitecture, the skill bot only send messages to the user, not the consumer bot, so for me it was no necessary to add another condition to process only messages sent by the skill bot (but it would be a good idea to add it). Finally I have to register the middleware in the bot adapter. So in the class AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs, I have to add the following line at the end of adapter: **Use(new GetSkillResponseMiddleware());**

```
public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger)
        : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
        {
            // Log any leaked exception from the application.
            // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to
            // Azure Application Insights. Visit https://aka.ms/bottelemetry to see how
            // to add telemetry capture to your bot.
            logger.LogError(exception, $"[OnTurnError] unhandled error : {exception.Message}");

            // Send a message to the user
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("The bot encountered an error or bug.");
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.");

            // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in the Bot Framework Emulator
            await turnContext.TraceActivityAsync("OnTurnError Trace", exception.Message, "https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error", "TurnError");
        };

        Use(new GetSkillResponseMiddleware());
    }
```

Hope my answer helps you and I would be glad to see some recomendations to improve this code. Greetings.